# javascript mock import in component with jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, mocking, jestjs

any idea how to mock an “import” for testing?
I use jest now.

ie:

```
//browser.js
export const browser = {
    id: undefined
};
export const getBrowser = function() {
    return browser;
};


//fetch-data.js
//code that uses the browser and I wanna test
import {getBrowser} from './../components/browser';

export const fetchData = function() {
     const browser = getBrowser();
     return Object.assign({dontcare:1}, browser);
};



//My test... Im using jest
import {fetchData} from './../fetch-data.js';
    expect(fetchData()).toBe({......});
};
```

now in the test file I want to mock the response of the `browser` component…

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Got to resolve it in the end with the help of one of the posts but in a different way with Sinnon.js

1) I import the browser component in my test:

```
import * as browserModule from './../components/browser';
```

2) now in my tests I'll mock the methods I want:

```
 sinon.stub(browserModule, 'getBrowser').returns({id: 1});
```

3) all good from here, I call my test object and it gets the proper mocked responses :)

Answer (score 0):

you need to find a way to inject the the `getBrowser` function into the fetchData

```
export const fetchData = function(injectedFunction) {
     const browser = injectedFunction !== undefined?  injectedFunction() || getBrowser();
     return Object.assign({dontcare:1}, browser);
};
```

this way you can now 
//your test... Im using jest

```
import {fetchData} from './../fetch-data.js';
import {getBrowser} from './../components/browser';
    let mockBrowser = mock(getBrowser);// <choose your mock library>
    // mock the behavior then inject it to the fetchData 
    expect(fetchData(mockBrowser)).toBe({......});
};
```

that's why it is good to apply **dependency injection** in your code to be able to test it with ease

for me you can use http://sinonjs.org/ for test spies, stubs and mocks

Comment: For sure, using DI in other languages, but never saw any DI for js. Any recommendations?

Comment: you can just pass parameter in it and check the parameter if **undefined** or not. the only purpose for that is you can mock the **object/method** for testing and nothing else. in your test you can pass the mock **object/method** but in production code you're not passing the **object/method**. the line `const browser = injectedFunction !== undefined?  injectedFunction() || getBrowser();` will do that for you

Comment: if the parameter is undefined it will execute the getBrowser() as the code if the parameter is undefined execute the parameter. this way you have the way to mock what's inside of the execution

Answer (score 0):

Your function in `fetch-data.js` is **dependent** upon **exports** from `browser.js`.

You would find that `browser` and `getBrowser` both are *undefined* depending on your [jest configuration](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html).

Since `browser.js` is *ready* for export, you can use `jest.requireActual(moduleName)` to import and use that module in`fetch-data.js`. I would do this in the following way:

```js
jest.mock("./browser", () => {
    const br = jest.requireActual("browser");
    return { 
       ...br, 
       browser: {id:'changed value'} 
    };
})
```